# Appending string to a list of strings

Tags: python, list

```
import re
red_dict= {u'Jharkhand': ['jarka09', 'jarka05'],
 u'Karnataka': ['karnataka2013', 'karnatka2008']}
for key, value in red_dict.items():
    num = re.findall(r'\d+',' '.join(value))
    map(lambda x: x if len(x)==4 else '20'+x, num)
    print num
```

Getting the result

```
['09', '05']
['2013', '2008']
```

Why wasn't '20' appended to the two digit list items?

For ordinary use, I can verify that this approach works

```
l = ['a','b','cd']
map(lambda x:x if len(x)==2 else 'e'+x,l)
```

gives

```
['ea', 'eb', 'cd']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) does not replace the given `num`. You should assign the return value back to `num`.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> map(lambda x: x + 1, a)
[2, 3, 4]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a = map(lambda x: x + 1, a)
>>> a
[2, 3, 4]
```

---

```
num = map(lambda x: x if len(x)==4 else '20'+x, num)
#^^^^
```

Answer (score 4):

@falsetru's answer might solve your issue, but just a well formed `regex` could actually do your Job without any post processing with `map`

**Implementation**

```
for key, value in red_dict.items():
    print [re.sub("^[^\d]+20|[^\d]+", "20", v) for v in value]
```

**Demo**

```
['2009', '2005']
['2013', '2008']
```

**Note**

For your particular case, you would actually not even need a Regex. You can simply slice out the trailing two characters and append it to `'20'`

```
for key, value in red_dict.items():
    print ['20' + v[-2:] for v in value]
```

Comment: Use `\D` instead of `[^\d]`. + Use `r'raw string'` for regular expression (especially if there's any backslash).